# GLTFJSX Error : Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'read-pkg-up'

Tags: react-three-fiber, npx, react-three-drei

I have a 3D .glb model and I want to convert it to a JSX file, there I herd about gltfjsx library, but when I ran the command : `npx gltfjsx /path/model.glb` I got an Error;

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'read-pkg-up' imported from /Users/xyz/.npm/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/gltfjsx/cli.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

Unable to export the .glb file to .jsx but got an Error. Anyone has a solution please react :)

Note: For assurance I have tried converting my .glb file to a .jsx using Official site of react three fiber https://gltf.pmnd.rs/ and it works totally fine, I got an output file of model.jsx, but somehow the npx gltfjsx cli doesn't work.